# How to align columns that contain matching string in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm struggling with this simple Excel formula because my knowledge is too limited. Hours of Google didn't get me the exact thing I need. Which is actually very simple:

I have one column with website URL's (column B)
And I have one column with e-mail addresses. (Column D)

However, because the two columns came from different sources they are not aligned. So the email addresses are not horizontally aligned with their belonging web address.

I need a formula which takes the domain name of email address and looks for that part of the string in the URL column, and then return the e-mailaddress in column C, nicely aligned to the corresponding web address in Column B.

Answer (score 2):

This is a surprisingly simple formula once wildcards are introduced to a `MATCH` function.

[image]

The standard formula in C2 is `=INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH("*"&REPLACE(B2,1,FIND("@",B2),"")&"*", $A$2:$A$5,0))`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to test this by using the same table as yours. However when I put in the formula, the B2 and second $A$2:$A$5 are just converted to plain text. They are not referencing anymore and I can't make them to. When I try to repair the references the field gets a dotted line and the formula says +B2. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @NvdB31 - Look into the [HYPERLINK function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/hyperlink-function-HP010062412.aspx) if you want to make an active link. You should be able to provide part or all of that formula for the *link_location* and/or *friendly_name*.